# Rails fails to install on Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, macos-sierra

(Thank you maxple for your answer! That worked)

I'm attempting to install Rails on macOS 10.12 (Sierra). I'm using Terminal to install it using this command:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

This produces the following output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/ext/nokogiri
/Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170111-22393-xqzt1j.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:547:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/paullantow/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/gem_make.out
```

I've installed the XCode command line tools (8.21), the lack of which is the common reason that I've seen when searching for others with this problem.

I have multiple versions of Ruby installed, using RVM.

I've also uninstalled and reinstalled homebrew.

I would appreciate any advice to getting Rails up and running on my system.

Comment: if you're using RVM, you shouldn't be using `sudo` with `gem install`. You have one 'base' ruby version that comes bundled on your computer, call it 'system' ruby. Then RVM installs other versions (allowing you to manage versions, as Ruby Version Manager implies), directing `gem install` to those versions. `sudo gem install` uses the system version. That may not solve your issue installing Nokogiri (a common issue, I might add) but it's worth knowing.

Comment: By the way, see Nokogiri's notes on troubleshooting OSX installation: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x

Comment: As @mxple said, you NEVER use sudo when using a ruby version manager.  The [rbenv docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-gems) say: _You don't need sudo to install gems. Typically, the Ruby versions will be installed and writeable by your user. No extra privileges are required to install gems._ That isn't strong enough language.  The rbenv docs should say NEVER, EVER, EVER use sudo.  `libxml` is a dependency of nokogiri, and it can be a pain to install, so nokogiri started including libxml inside nokogiri--but you had a problem compiling nokogiri's libxml. Report the bug.

Comment: I don't know if you tried bypassing nokogir's libxml and using the system's libxml as described here: https://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby/fixing-nokogiri-installation-macos-sierra/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

gem update --system

then:

xcode-select --install

then:

gem install nokogiri

and finally:

install the rails gem

Answer (score 17):

try using

`gem install nokogiri -v 1.7.0.1 -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2`

Comment: Why this is not market as the right answer?
worked on mac Sierra with gem install nokogiri -v 1.7.2 as well.

Comment: It's better to use nokogiri's packaged version of libxml, because it's been checked for compatibility. The build instructions state "Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors."